# Default style of input somehow messes up design

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc-3

For some reason the default styling of inputs in ASP.NET mvc3 applications are changing the look of my buttons.

if i apply the style to a normal div or actionlink the button looks just fine

when i apply it to my:

```
<input type="submit" value="create" class="universalbutton" />
```

the button doesnt recieve the right size but it does recieve color and background-color etc.

any ideas why this is happening?

// edit style of buttons

```
    .universalbutton 
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #3fa9f5;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    color: White;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    padding: 5px;
    text-transform: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;

}
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate an example?  Maybe on jsfiddle?

Comment: can you show the style definition of universalbutton class ?

Comment: i tried making a jsfiddle thingie: http://jsfiddle.net/6AbBy/ not sure if it helps. but the button needs to be larger and the text centeret

Comment: i cleaned up the jsfiddle a bit - http://jsfiddle.net/6AbBy/1/ - color and background-color seem to be fine?

Comment: yes. everything is correct except that the normal size of the button is larger and more symetric. perhaps try and add a div with the styling to see the difference

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6AbBy/2/ updated with the size the button really should have :S

Answer (score 1):

If it's just the height + alignment that's the problem, i'd suggest you change the box-sizing property on the input element. Input elements by default use border-box sizing (padding + margin isn't added to the height), div use content-box sizing (padding + width is added to the height).
This property is IE8+ only, though.

http://jsfiddle.net/6AbBy/10/

My first thought was to fix this with just some extra padding - though I must admit the vertical alignment of the text inside the button is very strange - no idea why it's aligned to the bottom - would be nice if someone else could explain that.